# combobox result reset when change next combobox in dynamic html table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've created a dynamic html table with add and remove button. When I click 'add' button, a new row with combo box is inserted to the table. When I change the combo box (combo 1), another combo box (combo 2) based on combo 1 appear in the next column. Everything was fine until i add a new row. When I change combo 1 in the second row, the result of combo 2 in the first row is reset to default. Please help me solve this problem

This is what i've tried so far:

```
$('#t_bag').on('change', '#i_d_bag', function(e){
  var id_bg = $(this).parent().find('option:selected').val();
  $.ajax({type : "POST",
          dataType : "json",
          data : {id : id_bg},
          url : "<?php echo site_url('con_surat/combo_pic_dist'); ?>",
          success : function(data){ 
      var opsi  = '';
      $.each(data,function(index,items){
        opsi +="<option value ="+items.nip+">"+items.nama_lengkap+"</option>";
      });
      $('#t_bag tbody tr').each(function() {
        if($(this).parent().find('option:selected').val() != "*") {
          $(this).parent().find('#i_pic').show();
        }
        $(this).closest('tr').find('#i_pic').html(opsi);
      });
    }
  });
});
```